# QSlider direct jump on click

Tags: c++, qt

By default, QSlider move his thumbtrack by a value belonging to the singleStep() prop on mouse click. To make thumbtrack jump directly at the mouse click point, we need to create a new class inherited by QSlider.

Header file (.h):

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QAbstractSlider>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QStyleOptionSlider>
#ifndef QIMPROVEDSLIDER_H
#define QIMPROVEDSLIDER_H

class QImprovedSlider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

public:
    explicit QImprovedSlider(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~QImprovedSlider();

public slots:

private:

private slots:

signals:
    void onClick(int value);
};

#endif // QIMPROVEDSLIDER_H
```

Source file (.cpp):

```
#include "QImprovedSlider.h"


QImprovedSlider::QImprovedSlider(QWidget *parent) :
    QSlider(parent)
{

}

QImprovedSlider::~QImprovedSlider()
{
}

void QImprovedSlider::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
  QStyleOptionSlider opt;
  initStyleOption(&opt);
  QRect sr = style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_Slider, &opt, QStyle::SC_SliderHandle, this);

  if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton &&
      !sr.contains(event->pos())) {
    int newVal;
    if (orientation() == Qt::Vertical) {
       double halfHandleHeight = (0.5 * sr.height()) + 0.5;
       int adaptedPosY = height() - event->y();
       if ( adaptedPosY < halfHandleHeight )
             adaptedPosY = halfHandleHeight;
       if ( adaptedPosY > height() - halfHandleHeight )
             adaptedPosY = height() - halfHandleHeight;
       double newHeight = (height() - halfHandleHeight) - halfHandleHeight;
       double normalizedPosition = (adaptedPosY - halfHandleHeight)  / newHeight ;

       newVal = minimum() + (maximum()-minimum()) * normalizedPosition;
    } else {
        double halfHandleWidth = (0.5 * sr.width()) + 0.5;
        int adaptedPosX = event->x();
        if ( adaptedPosX < halfHandleWidth )
              adaptedPosX = halfHandleWidth;
        if ( adaptedPosX > width() - halfHandleWidth )
              adaptedPosX = width() - halfHandleWidth;
        double newWidth = (width() - halfHandleWidth) - halfHandleWidth;
        double normalizedPosition = (adaptedPosX - halfHandleWidth)  / newWidth ;

        newVal = minimum() + ((maximum()-minimum()) * normalizedPosition);
    }

    if (invertedAppearance())
        this->setValue( maximum() - newVal );
    else
        this->setValue(newVal);

    event->accept();
  }
  else {
        QSlider::mousePressEvent(event);
  }
  emit onClick(this->value());
}
```

This code works well, so is not a broken code. There is a way to improve this? Maybe trying to differentiate the direct jump from the handle dragging

Answer (score 2):

One issue I see, that has to do with functionality: since you are working with doubles, but your end values are integers, perhaps you should round the result.

The code above will set the handle one step before the end when you position the mouse at the end.

To fix, round the new position: replace

```
newVal = minimum() + ((maximum()-minimum()) * normalizedPosition);
```

with

```
newVal = minimum() + qRound((maximum()-minimum()) * normalizedPosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (invertedAppearance()) {
        this->setValue( maximum() - newVal ); 
} else {
        this->setValue(newVal);
}
```

You should not be posting `if/else` statements without Curly Braces. The style leaves you open for massive bugs, and as an after thought: makes it cumbersome for you or other developers to add to this code.

So for example, let's say you are editing or debugging your code, and decide to comment out a line:

```
if (invertedAppearance())
    this->setValue( maximum() - newVal );
else
    // this->setValue(newVal); 

event->accept();
```

Do you see the issue?